# Excel SERIESSUM won't accept array of cell references as coefficients

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

The Google Sheets version of "SERIESSUM" function accepts an array of cell references for the "list" of coefficients as in this example:

`=SERIESSUM(O8549,0,1,{K8549,K8538,K8526,K8514,K8502,K8490,K8478,K8466,K8454,K8442,K8430,K8418})`

However, Excel refuses to accept this and apparently only will accept a cell "range" or a list of constants. Any way to overcome this. I have scoured the internet for info....
I need for the coefficients to be in column "K" and every 12th row (they are atmospheric readings taken every 5 minutes and column "K" is the running average of the last hour) - my coeffs need to be the hourly average for each of the last 12 hours.
Someone suggested creating a custom function, but how will that populate the coeff list in Excel with constants (and my VBA skills are VERY rusty/lacking)?
BDR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the number of coefficients is fixed at 12, you can use `CHOOSE`:

```
=SERIESSUM(
    O8549,
    0,
    1,
    CHOOSE(
        {1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12},
        K8549,
        K8538,
        K8526,
        K8514,
        K8502,
        K8490,
        K8478,
        K8466,
        K8454,
        K8442,
        K8430,
        K8418
    )
)
```

Comment: Awesome, Just tested the "CHOOSE" function-based option and it works great! Don't need to maintain the "coefficients" table for each row (keeps all of the data for one reading in one row). AND it functions on all version of Excel we are using (Excel 2013 mostly and Excel 2019). Thank You! We are collecting atmospheric data, including Air Quality  values (particulate matter and calculating AQI - important with fire season here in the NW) every 5 minutes and updating all of those tables was going to be another chore for someone. Thanks Again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in Excel you can't put cell references into an array with braces like that.

You can try building the coefficients like this (edit your ranges appropriately):

```
=CHOOSEROWS($B$1:$B$61,SEQUENCE(ROWS($B$1:$B$61)/12+1,,1,12))
```

And placing them in the SERIESSUM:

```
=SERIESSUM(0.6,0,1,CHOOSEROWS($B$1:$B$61,SEQUENCE(ROWS($B$1:$B$61)/12+1,,1,12)))
```

Or to make it a bit neater:

```
=LET(
  data,$B$1:$B$61,
  every,12,
  coeffs,CHOOSEROWS(data,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)/every+1,,1,every)),
  SERIESSUM(0.6,0,1,coeffs)
)
```

**EDIT - possible solution for Excel 2013**

In an empty column, use a variant of this formula to grab the coefficients:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$61,IF(ROW()=1,ROW(),(ROW()-1)*12))
```

[image]

Adjust the range and offsets based on the position of your data in your worksheet and the exact requirements for nth row.

Then pass the range holding the coefficients into the SERIESSUM function:

```
=SERIESSUM(0.6,0,1,D1:D6)
```

Comment: Looks like a great solution. However, "CHOOSEROWS" is not a function in Microsoft Excel 2013.....  But is available in the 365 products. I will check with our IT Dept on Monday to see if  it's possible to change to that product....

Comment: @bridaho Ah yes sorry about that. I didn't see the Excel 2013 tag. I've edited my answer to add a possible alternative for Excel 2013.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and suggestion for Excel 2013. However, each row must be its own calculation and I can't use some rows in an empty column, because the next row would need those cells for different values. HOWEVER, your solution made me come up with a solution which is to maintain a separate tab (worksheet) for coefficients for each row. So, the formula becomes: =SERIESSUM(O8549,0,1,COEFFS1!A8549:L8549)
Good for now, until we change to Office 365/Excel 2022 and I can use your more elegant solution!